# Group By Count in MySql (Users and Group)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm creating a social mobile-application which has groups and groups can have user. I'm trying to write a query in order to get all the groups along with number of users in it.

Note: Group can have 0 users as well.

Even if group has zero user, I still need to get its information. How should I do that? I tried:

```
Select *, count(ug.group_id) from groups g 
left join images i ON(g.group_image_id = i.image_id)
left join location l ON(g.group_location_id = l.location_id)
.
.
left join user_group ug on(ug.gorup_id = g.group_id)
group by ug.group_id;
```

Now, this query does not give me group that has zero user(s). How can change it so it shows all group even if group has 0 users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SELECT * and GROUP BY is a MySQL abomination. In your case, it doesn't look like it hurts since `image` and `location` appear to have a *0:1* relation ship with `group`. It's just very bad practice.

Here's an ANSI compliant way to write your query.  If you want the full result set from JOINing a few tables, plus the count, then add *only the count portion* as an expression.

```
Select *, (select count(ug.group_id)
           from user_group ug
           where ug.gorup_id = g.group_id) GroupUserCount
from groups g 
left join images i ON(g.group_image_id = i.image_id)
left join location l ON(g.group_location_id = l.location_id)
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

you should group them from `groups` table

```
GROUP BY g.group_id
```

Comment: This usage of `GROUP BY` should be discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like:

```
Select g.group_id,coalesce(users ,0)
from groups g 
  left join (select ug.gorup_id,count(*) users
from user_group ug
group by ug.gorup_id) s
on s.group_id = g.group_id
```

If you only need to know the group and number of users, the other table in the example are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your are grouping by a column of your left join, this means that your are grouping by null when a group have no users.

You need to group by id of the groups table and the count(*) will count the number of joined rows.

Then add the empty groups using a left join and where join row is null

```
Select g.group_id as groupId, count(*) as nb
    from groups g 
       join user_group ug on (ug.group_id = g.group_id)
    group by g.group_id
UNION ALL
    Select g.group_id as groupId, 0 as nb
    from groups g 
       left join user_group ug on (ug.group_id = g.group_id)
where ug.group_id is null
    group by g.group_id
```

[EDIT] One query count looking for null join in the select statement and setting nb to 0 if found

```
Select g.group_id as groupId, IF(ug.group_id is null, 0,count(*)) as nb
    from groups g 
       left join user_group ug on (ug.group_id = g.group_id)
    group by g.group_id
```